# Rake Cannot Load Such File

Tags: ruby

I have installed the state_machine gem.  "gem list" reports it installed locally.  I am actually using the gem successfully.

```
$ ruby peer_state_machine_test.rb
```

runs great.  However when I try to rake, I hit a failure to load that gem.

```
peer_state_machine.rb:1:in `require': cannot load such file state_machine (LoadError)
```

The line of the file in question is:

```
require 'state_machine'
```

I'm confused as to how there is any difference in the way ruby loads this file and rake loads it.  There are many other test files which are running without any problems.  This is on OS X if it matters.

Comment: `require` works by looking on `$LOAD_PATH` for the first file called `state_machine.rb`. A quick way to see your default `$LOAD_PATH` is: `ruby -e 'puts $:'`. To see what it is in the context of a `rake` command, create a file called `Rakefile` with these contents: `task :x do; puts $:; end` and run `rake x`. On my machine, the plain Ruby `$LOAD_PATH` is a subset of the one in the `rake` context. If you have the same situation, the `LoadError` could mean that a "bad" version of `state_machine.rb` lives somewhere on the `rake`-context `$LOAD_PATH` before any location on the plain `$LOAD_PATH`.

Comment: Instead of `require 'state_machine'`, try: `require_relative './state_machine'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was writing a gem and forgot to add the state_mahine gem as a development dependency to my gemspec. Adding

```
spec.add_development_dependency "state_machine", "~> 1.2.0"
```

resolved the problem.